Is it possible to use Azure Durable Functions to "replace" pipelines in Azure Synapse Analytics
We are currently using Azure Synapse Analytics to read data from linked services and store it in the DLH. Not much more is happening. My boss asked to look into Durable Functions to see if we could use them for the process, in order to save money on the pipelines.
I am now stuck as i managed to copy data from one blob to another, but have not yet found a way to read data from a linked service using azure functions.
Is there a way to do this? And does it even make sense to use Azure Durable Functions instead of pipelines?

Yes, Using Azure synapse pipelines or Copy tool for data movement from source Linked service to sink Linked service is the ideal way. As Synapse and Data factory has built in connectors that makes the data copy job easier. Where as Durable Function won't be ideal for processing large scale of data with million rows. As Azure synapse is ideal data-warehouse solution for the same. But you can create Azure durable function and carry out activity to transfer data from one blob to another. You can create normal Function with blob trigger,  Blob trigger function triggers as soon as new file is uploaded in the Azure storage blob container. And then you can carry out task to copy the uploaded blob to another blob by adding output binding to destination blob. You can also create basic Http Trigger and call blob clients to copy the blob from one container to another or from one storage account to another.
Also, To interact with your Linked service you need to call that client specific sdk.
Using Blob trigger Function:-
init.py:-
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(myblob: func.InputStream, outputBlob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    outputBlob.set(myblob.read())


function.json:-
Added input binding to get the blob and output binding to copy the blob:-

{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "data/{name}",
      "connection": "siddheshstrg_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "copy-data/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "siddheshstrg_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}

Output:-

Uploaded a file in Source blob:-

Source blob file copied to destination blob:-

Using Durable Function trigger:-
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
import azure.functions as func
from azure.durable_functions import DurableOrchestrationContext, Orchestrator


def orchestrator_function(context: DurableOrchestrationContext):
    source_container = "data"
    source_blob_name = "7xxxx.html"
    destination_container = "copy-data"
    destination_blob_name = "test.html"
    copy_result = yield context.call_activity("CopyBlobActivity", {
        "source_container": source_container,
        "source_blob_name": source_blob_name,
        "destination_container": destination_container,
        "destination_blob_name": destination_blob_name
    })

    return copy_result

main = Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)

def copy_blob_activity(context: DurableOrchestrationContext, input_data: dict) -> str:
    source_container = input_data["source_container"]
    source_blob_name = input_data["source_blob_name"]
    destination_container = input_data["destination_container"]
    destination_blob_name = input_data["destination_blob_name"]

    source_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxrg;AccountKey=dxxxxxxxXdtA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    destination_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxhstrg;AccountKey=dxxxxxxxEG+AStYRXdtA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    
    source_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(source_connection_string)
    destination_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(destination_connection_string)

    source_blob_client = source_blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=source_container, blob=source_blob_name)

    blob_data = source_blob_client.download_blob().readall()

    destination_blob_client = destination_blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=destination_container, blob=destination_blob_name)
    destination_blob_client.upload_blob(blob_data, overwrite=True)

    return f"Blob '{source_blob_name}' copied to '{destination_container}/{destination_blob_name}'"


Thanks! What i am trying to do seems simple enough. I just want to connect to a linked service to get Data (OData) and then copy that data into my blob container. You said:
Also, To interact with your Linked service you need to call that client specific sdk.
Do you have any more information on that? As the linked service connection from the function seems to be the crucial step that i just cant figure out.

Which linked service are you using? Azure sql? ADLS? or self hosted linked service?

2 kinds, either self hosted or AutoResolvedIntegrationRuntime and always using the Odata Connector

AutoResolveIntergationRumtime with which azure services?
